# cordova 5.0.0 , android 4.0.2 weird versionCode behavior

Tags: android, cordova

in my root config.xml, this is the config for android version code

```
<widget id="com.michael.myapp" android-versionCode="11" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

When I build release for android and sign it ( using this http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), then upload to Google App Store, the App Store tells me my the Version Code is 110 and Version name is 1.0.0.

If I dont have "android-versionCode = '1'", the default Version Code is 10.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: What is the version code shown in `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="11" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.michael.myapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

Comment: That is weird, `versionCode` is kind of irrelevant, it just has to be incremented by 1 each time your version changes. I've used Cordova and here's the screenshot from Playstore - http://puu.sh/i4V1f/dbf4a33284.png. **2** is the `versionCode`,

Comment: This is mine ( http://screencast.com/t/xlrx7N7P8 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed my problem. It is a bug with Cordova 5.0.0 ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8976 ), in platforms/android/build.gradle

change

```
versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode") + "0")
```

to

```
versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: Integer.parseInt("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
```